# RecursiveIteratorIterator not ignoring .svn

Tags: php

I have the following PHP code that loops through files recursively and should be ignoring anything prefixed with a dot.

```
$objects = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($directory, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS));
foreach($objects as $name => $object) 
{
    var_dump($object);exit;
[...]
```

However it isn't ignoring .svn folders. The output of the dump is:

```
object(SplFileInfo)#8 (2) { ["pathName":"SplFileInfo":private]=> string(42) "C:\import\Drinks\.svn\dir-prop-base" ["fileName":"SplFileInfo":private]=> string(13) "dir-prop-base" }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because [RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS](http://php.net/manual/en/class.filesystemiterator.php#filesystemiterator.constants) is not supposed to ignore hidden files:

> FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS
>
> Skips dot files (`.` and `..`).

It only ignores the special directory names mentioned in documentation.